UILabel Text Cutting Issue During Screen Recording in UITableViewCell
I’m experiencing an issue with a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell on iOS. The UILabel is set to display multiple lines of text and does not have a fixed height constraint. Everything works fine while scrolling the UITableView, but when I start screen recording on the device, the text in the UILabel gets cut off or is not fully visible.
Details:

UILabel Configuration:
The UILabel is set up to support multiple lines of text with numberOfLines set to 0. There is no fixed height constraint applied to the UILabel.

UITableViewCell Configuration:
The cell's height is dynamic, and it adjusts based on the content of the UILabel.

Issue:
When screen recording is started, the text in the UILabel is cut off or not displayed correctly.


Additional Information:
iOS Version: 17.14.1
Device Model: All iOS Device
Screen Recording Tool: Apple Default Screen Recording
Expected Behavior:
The UILabel text should be fully visible and correctly displayed during screen recording, just as it is during normal scrolling.
Actual Behavior:
During screen recording, the text in the UILabel appears cut off or is not fully visible.

Did you check the label constraints on both vertical and horizontal?

It's super hard to reconstruct the view you have with your details. Did you create the view in storyboard or code? Maybe you could share a snippet or show a screenshot of your Storyboard settings? There is probably a constraint issue or something.
